# Как произвести мат. вычисление строки "10+2"

Tags: java

Делаю калькулятор, хочу что бы при нажатии клавиши `=` из текстового поля `JTextarea` считалась строка например `10+2` и затем производилось мат. вычисление. 
Пытался поэлементно перевести `String->Int`, но как быть с символом операции?

Comment: Символ операции должен определять операцию для вычисления.

Answer (score 4):

Если задача в том, чтобы вычислить простейшее выражение `v1 +-*/ v2`, то можно просто посимвольно пробежаться в цикле по исходной строке и сформировать в итоге три строки: первая и третья - операнды, вторая - операция. Проверить является ли строка или символ числом можно с помощью метода `isDigit()`. Получив символ операции используйте `if-else` или `switch` для определения, что это за операция и что нужно сделать впоследствии.

Если задача написать калькулятор любой строки с поддержкой приоритетов, множества операций и даже функций, то либо алгоритм на основе стека, который хорошо описан в книге *Роберта Седжвика "Алгоритмы на Java"*, либо можно *методом рекурсивного спуска*, если знакомы чутка с теорией компиляторов.

Comment: Еще методом тыка можно

Comment: Ну эт совсем хардкор)

Comment: обычно в калькуляторах используется [обратная польская нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_польская_запись), наколько я знаю.

Comment: Идея! А возможно ли введенный пример с помощью рефлексии вбить в переменную? Ведь все правила скобок уже в коде учитываются..... А, нет, будет же строка

Comment: @pavlofff ну да, к ней тоже можно привести, правда для вычислений этого явно делать обычно не нужно. Метод рекурсивного спуска позволяет сделать в принципе все, что угодно с математическим выражением. Можно тупо построить дерево, а потом хоть в ОПН выводи, хоть считай...

Answer (score -1):

Считать его в отдельную переменную и через `switch` реализовать выбор нужного действия.

Answer (score -1):

Покопался на просторах интернета и нашел решение при помощи JavaScript:

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
            String s1 = text.getText();
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            try {
               Object s2 = engine.eval(s1);
               text.setText(s2.toString());
            }
            catch (ScriptException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```